# Результаты прогона в allure не отображаются в TestRail

Tags: jenkins, allure

**Шаги**:

1. Настраиваю проект в Jenkins с плагином публикации результатов в TestRail в Post-Build Actions
2. Прогоняю тест
3. Смотрю результаты в Allure
4. Смотрю результат прогона билда в TestRail

**Ожидаемый результат**:

Вижу результат прогона в Аллюре

Вижу результат прогона в ТестРейл

**Фактический результат**:

Результат прогона в Allure виден

Результат прогона в TestRail не виден

***Вопрос***: как получить xml-файл результата прогона в Allure и выгрузить его в TestRail и как вообще правильно настраивать интеграцию между ними

[image: результат прогона]

[image: настройка плагина]

Answer (score 1):

TestRail не поддерживает формат данных Аллюра.

[В описании](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/TestRail+Plugin) TestRail Jenkins Plugin сказано, что он поддерживает выгрузку XML в формате JUnit.

Comment: Смотрю, имя знакомое. Неспроста )

Comment: Значит, я должен просить у Allure результат в виде XML-репорт, затем отправлять в JUnit, после обработки которым полученный результат отправляю в TesRail?

Comment: для JUnit тестов обычно по-умолчанию генерируется XML отчет в его формате (при использовании surefire в Maven - в папку `${basedir}/target/surefire-reports` , в Gradle в папку `build/test-results/test`). Их и нужно отправлять в TestRail